# Is there a linux vfs tool that allows bind a directory in different location (like mount --bind) in user space?

Tags: linux, mount, chroot, non-root-user

For a user process, I want to mount a directory in other location but in user space without root privilieges. Something like mount --bind /origin /dest, but with a vfs wrapper. Like a usermode fine-tuned chroot.

The program would wrapper the syscalls to files to "substitute" the paths needed. It could be called with a command line like:

bindvfs /fake-home:/home ls /home

I am sure that this alredy exists! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [PRoot](http://proot.me) almost the same way as in your example:

```
proot -b /fake-home:/home ls /home
```

Unlike BindFS/FUSE, PRoot is able to bind over files and directories you don't own.

Comment: Perfect, that is exactly what I was thinking on

Comment: Some other ptrace-based approaches -- http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/72697/4319 .

Answer (score 2):

The [parrot](http://www.cse.nd.edu/~ccl/software/parrot/) program can
do what you ask for: intercept system calls and redirect certain
paths (e.g., all paths starting with `/anonftp` are remapped to
transparently access remote files over FTP).  It also runs entirely in
userspace.

However, despite an impressive array of common and uncommon network
protocols, `parrot` does not have any module to do simple
filesystem->filesystem rewriting like you ask for.  That should be
quite simple to add, if you know some C language programming.

Alternatively, [bindfs](http://code.google.com/p/bindfs/) (which
runs on top of [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/)), works like a
`mount --bind` in userspace.  (But this goes in the reverse direction
relative to re-directing `/home` to `/fake-home` as you mention in your question.)

Comment: I did not knwon that program, parrot. I will mail them.

Answer (score 1):

VFS already allows for non-root mounting of filesystems.  You can add the `user` or `users` option to the fstab entry and make sure `vfs.usermount=1` is in `/etc/sysctl`.

None of this will give you chroot-like controls however.  The `bind` option isn't going to change permissions or allow for an 'alternate' access, this is a second mtab entry for the same exact filesystem and contents.  Modifications in the bind mount affect the original.

I'd make sure you clarify your end goal before moving further.

Comment: Well imagine this situation: I have a precompiled program, that I can not recompile. This program access to a fixed path, like '~/.program-data' and I need to launch several instances of the program as user, without doing chroot. Of course I could create a chrooted environment and use fakechroot, but it is too complex.

Comment: So in that instance you are trying to provide a shared location (like `/var/program-data`) for users to all access as `~/.program-data` when running said program?  Or are you trying to provide separate copies of `~/.program-data` to each instance of a program run by the same user?

Comment: Both situations are ok. If can be by process instance, better.

Answer (score 0):

mount_namespaces will allow you to do `mount --bind` not seen by other processes. But normally `mount --bind` is restricted to the root user only (for security reasons). So, for mount_namespaces to be of some use to a non-root user, you should first use [user_namespaces](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/303213/4319) to become a "local root" in a new namespace, where this operation would be allowed then.

You can play with this in your shell like this -- this examples specifically shows the use of user&mount spaces in preparation of a chroot directory (and the `chroot` operation is normally privileged, too):

```
unshare --user --map-root-user --mount-proc --pid --fork
mkdir -p newroot/dev
mount --rbind /dev newroot/dev
....other chroot preparation....
chroot newroot
su - user1
```

Note, that I'm using `mount --rbind` (instead of `mount --bind`), because only this will work in the new user&mount namespace, if the directory includes other mount points (and `/dev/` does in my case).

Perhaps the explanation for this is that the user should not get a way to see something what normally an unprivileged user wouldn't see, i.e., the subdirectories hidden by the "submounts". Not to strip the submounts, only `--rbind` is allowed.