# How to "jail" a process without being root?

Tags: permissions, non-root-user, jails

Were I root, I could simply create a dummy user/group, set file permissions accordingly and execute the process as that user. However I am not, so is there any way to achieve this without being root?

Comment: The real question is: why do you need that?  You don't trust what the process can do you the files you have access to?

Comment: @alex: I have a script executing multiple simulations (in different directories) and want to make sure no matter how bad the programming they can only access files in their own directory and not accidentally modify e.g. the output of the other simulations

Comment: @Tobias: I got your point.  `chroot` would naturally fit there, but then again you're not root.

Comment: I think that selinux, apparmor, and grsecurity, *might* be able to do this, but I'm not sure. but then if those aren't available or configured by the sys admin, you're sol on that.

Comment: Such a question has been something for me to wonder about for years. It seems to be such a natural wish: without being root, to be able to run processes with some of your user's permissions discarded, i.e. to be able to confine a process to a user-setup "jail", which would give the process even less rights than your user has. It's a pity that the usual Unices haven't offered this standardly!

Comment: @imz: that's exactly my point! actually I wanted to go even further and ask something like "can a user be root but only wrt his account"

Comment: But well, of course, the desired "jail" guarantees are implementable by programming in user-space; with more or less complications.

Comment: Try asking your system administrator to make you a second user account.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

More similar Qs with more answers worth attention:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/3859710/94687
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/4410447/94687
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/4249063/94687
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/1019707/94687

**NOTE:** Some of the answers there point to specific solutions not yet mentioned here.

Actually, there are quite a few jailing tools with different implementation, but many of them are either not secure by design (like `fakeroot`, `LD_PRELOAD`-based), or not complete (like `fakeroot-ng`, `ptrace`-based), or would require root (`chroot`, or `plash` mentioned at [fakechroot warning label](http://joey.kitenet.net/blog/entry/fakechroot_warning_label)).

These are just examples; I thought of listing them all side-by-side, with indication of these 2 features ("can be trusted?", "requires root to set up?"), perhaps at [Operating-system-level virtualization Implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system-level_virtualization#Implementations).

In general, the answers there cover the full described range of possibilities and even more:

## virtual machines/OS

- ([the answer mentioning virtual machines/OS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6433/how-to-jail-a-process-without-being-root/6455#6455))

## kernel extension (like SELinux)

- (mentioned in comments here),

## chroot

Chroot-based helpers (which however must be setUID root, because `chroot` requires root; or perhaps `chroot` could work in an isolated namespace--see below):

[to tell a little more about them!]

#### Known chroot-based isolation tools:

- [hasher](http://en.altlinux.org/Hasher) with its `hsh-run` and `hsh-shell` commands. (*Hasher* was designed for building software in a safe and repeatable manner.)
- [schroot](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/566) mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3859727/94687)
- ...

## ptrace

Another trustworthy isolation solution (besides [a `seccomp`-based one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6433/how-to-run-a-process-with-restricted-file-permissions/8929#8929)) would be the complete syscall-interception through `ptrace`, as explained in the manpage for [`fakeroot-ng`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fakerootng):

> Unlike  previous  implementations,  fakeroot-ng  uses  a
>   technology that leaves the
>          traced process no choice regarding whether it will use
>   fakeroot-ng's "services"  or
>          not.  Compiling  a program statically, directly calling the
>   kernel and manipulating
>          ones own address space are all techniques that can  be  trivially 
>   used  to  bypass
>          LD_PRELOAD  based  control  over a process, and do not apply to
>   fakeroot-ng. It is,
>          theoretically, possible to mold fakeroot-ng in such a way as to have
>   total  control
>          over the traced process.
>
> While  it  is theoretically possible, it has not been done.
>   Fakeroot-ng does assume
>          certain "nicely behaved" assumptions about the process being
>   traced, and a  process
>          that  break  those  assumptions may be able to, if not totally escape
>   then at least
>          circumvent some of the "fake" environment imposed on it by 
>   fakeroot-ng.  As  such,
>          you  are  strongly warned against using fakeroot-ng as a
>   security tool. Bug reports
>          that claim that a process can deliberatly (as opposed to inadvertly)
>   escape  fake‐
>          root-ng's control will either be closed as "not a bug" or marked as
>   low priority.
>
> It  is  possible  that  this policy be rethought in the future. For
>   the time being,
>          however, you have been warned.

Still, as you can read it, `fakeroot-ng` itself is not designed for this purpose.

(BTW, I wonder why they have chosen to use the `seccomp`-based approach for Chromium rather than a `ptrace`-based...)

Of the tools not mentioned above, I have noted **[Geordi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859710/what-is-the-safest-way-to-run-an-executable-on-linux/3859784#3859784)** for myself, because I liked that the controlling program is written in Haskell.

#### Known ptrace-based isolation tools:

- [Geordi](http://www.eelis.net/geordi/)
- [proot](http://proot.me)
- [`fakeroot-ng`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fakerootng)
- ... (see also [How to achieve the effect of chroot in userspace in Linux (without being root)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/72697/4319))

## seccomp

One known way to achieve isolation is through [the seccomp sandboxing approach used in Google Chromium](http://www.imperialviolet.org/2009/08/26/seccomp.html). But this approach supposes that you write a helper which would process some (the allowed ones) of the "intercepted" file access and other syscalls; and also, of course, make effort to "intercept" the syscalls and redirect them to the helper (perhaps, it would even mean such a thing as replacing the intercepted syscalls in the code of the controlled process; so, it doesn't sound to be quite simple; if you are interested, you'd better read the details rather than just my answer).

More related info (from Wikipedia):

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seccomp
- http://code.google.com/p/seccompsandbox/wiki/overview
- [LWN article: Google's Chromium sandbox](http://lwn.net/Articles/347547/), Jake Edge, August 2009
- **[seccomp-nurse](http://chdir.org/~nico/seccomp-nurse/), a sandboxing framework based on seccomp.**

(The last item seems to be interesting if one is looking for a general `seccomp`-based solution outside of Chromium. There is also a blog post worth reading from the author of "seccomp-nurse": [SECCOMP as a Sandboxing solution ?](http://justanothergeek.chdir.org/2010/03/seccomp-as-sandboxing-solution.html).)

The illustration of this approach from [the "seccomp-nurse" project](http://chdir.org/~nico/seccomp-nurse/):

[image]

#### A "flexible" seccomp possible in the future of Linux?

There used to appear in 2009 also [suggestions to patch the Linux kernel](http://lwn.net/Articles/332438/) so that there is more flexibility to the `seccomp` mode--so that "many of the acrobatics that we currently need could be avoided". ("Acrobatics" refers to the complications of writing a helper that has to execute many possibly innocent syscalls on behalf of the jailed process and of substituting the possibly innocent syscalls in the jailed process.) [An LWN article](http://lwn.net/Articles/332438/) wrote to this point:

> One suggestion that came out was to
>   add a new "mode" to seccomp. The API
>   was designed with the idea that
>   different applications might have
>   different security requirements; it
>   includes a "mode" value which
>   specifies the restrictions that should
>   be put in place. Only the original
>   mode has ever been implemented, but
>   others can certainly be added.
>   Creating a new mode which allowed the
>   initiating process to specify which
>   system calls would be allowed would
>   make the facility more useful for
>   situations like the Chrome sandbox.
>
> Adam Langley (also of Google) has
>   posted a patch which does just that.
>   The new "mode 2" implementation
>   accepts a bitmask describing which
>   system calls are accessible. If one of
>   those is prctl(), then the sandboxed
>   code can further restrict its own
>   system calls (but it cannot restore
>   access to system calls which have been
>   denied). All told, it looks like a
>   reasonable solution which could make
>   life easier for sandbox developers.
>
> That said, this code may never be
>   merged because the discussion has
>   since moved on to other possibilities.

This "flexible seccomp" would bring the possibilities of Linux closer to providing the desired feature in the OS, without the need to write helpers that complicated.

(A blog posting with basically the same content as this answer: http://geofft.mit.edu/blog/sipb/33.)

## namespaces (`unshare`)

Isolating through namespaces (**`unshare`-based solutions**) -- not mentioned here -- e.g., [unsharing mount-points](http://karelzak.blogspot.com/2009/12/unshare1.html) (combined with FUSE?) could perhaps be a part of a working solution for you wanting to confine filesystem accesses of your untrusted processes.

More on namespaces, now, as their implementation has been completed (this isolation technique is also known under the nme **"Linux Containers", or "LXC"**, isn't it?..):

["One of the overall goals of namespaces is to support the implementation of containers, a tool for lightweight virtualization (as well as other purposes)"](https://lwn.net/Articles/531114/).

It's even possible to create a new user namespace, so that "a process can have a normal unprivileged user ID outside a user namespace while at the same time having a user ID of 0 inside the namespace. This means that the process has full root privileges for operations inside the user namespace, but is unprivileged for operations outside the namespace".

For real working commands to do this, see the answers at:

- [Is there a linux vfs tool that allows bind a directory in different location (like mount --bind) in user space?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/303663/4319)
- [Simulate chroot with unshare](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/303660/4319)

## and special user-space programming/compiling

But well, of course, the desired "jail" guarantees are implementable by programming in user-space (**without additional support for this feature from the OS**; maybe that's why this feature hasn't been included in the first place in the design of OSes); with more or less complications.

The mentioned [`ptrace`-](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6433/how-to-jail-a-process-without-being-root/8939#8939) or [`seccomp`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6433/how-to-jail-a-process-without-being-root/8929#8929)-based sandboxing can be seen as some variants of implementing the guarantees by writing a sandbox-helper that would control your other processes, which would be treated as "black boxes", arbitrary Unix programs.

Another approach could be to use programming techniques that can care about the effects that must be disallowed. (It must be you who writes the programs then; they are not black boxes anymore.) To mention one, using a **pure programming language** (which would force you to program without side-effects) like [Haskell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_(programming_language)#Features) will simply make all the effects of the program explicit, so the programmer can easily make sure there will be no disallowed effects.

I guess, there are sandboxing facilities available for those programming in some other language, e.g., Java.

- Cf. ["Sandboxed Haskell" project proposal](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/summer-of-code/ticket/1114).
- **[NaCl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249063/run-an-untrusted-c-program-in-a-sandbox-in-linux-that-prevents-it-from-opening-f)--not mentioned here**--belongs to this group, doesn't it?

---

Some pages accumulating info on this topic were also pointed at in the answers there:

- [page on Google Chrome's sandboxing methods for Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019707/sandboxing-in-linux/1020287#1020287)
- [sandboxing.org group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410447/how-to-disable-socket-creation-for-a-linux-process-for-sandboxing/4599355#4599355)

Comment: [Rootless GoboLinux](http://www.gobolinux.org/?page=rootless) might be an option as well...

Comment: @tobias But does Rootless Gobolinux give a guarantee that a program written by a user won't access the outer environment?..

Comment: Not really - I was somehow under the misconception that it would also allow one to become a "local" root user which then could simply create virtual users for such a process - though it might be possible to use its `chroot`, but that would probably still require real root privileges...

Answer (score 8):

This is a fundamental limitation of the unix permission model: only root can delegate.

You don't need to be root to run a virtual machine (not true of all VM technologies), but this is a heavyweight solution.

[User-mode Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_mode_Linux) is a relatively lightweight Linux-on-Linux virtualization solution. It's not that easy to set up; you'll need to populate a root partition (in a directory) with at least the minimum needed to boot (a few files in `/etc`, `/sbin/init` and its dependencies, a login program, a shell and utilities).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can have some luck with `LD_PRELOAD` to intercept access to certain files, but this might be really tricky.

Comment: Google Chromium's seccomp sandboxing does a more reliable thing--syscall interception, effectively. -- http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6433/how-to-run-a-process-with-restricted-file-permissions/8929#8929

Comment: The difference between just trying to intercept something and sanboxing (as in the case of Chromium) is the guarantee of the isolation.

Comment: Interception through `LD_PRELOAD` cannot be trusted (can be circumvented), but [interception through `ptrace`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6433/how-to-run-a-process-with-restricted-file-permissions/8939#8939) can.

Comment: A simple example is presented here <http://joey.kitenet.net/blog/entry/fakechroot_warning_label/> that shows that `LD_PRELOAD`-based solutions can't be trusted as a security measure.

Answer (score 1):

Firejail is nice tool to jail any process, with or without root access with a lot of options and very flexible:

- https://firejail.wordpress.com

Comment: A bit more detail on how to use firejail would be welcome. After that link goes dead, your answers information content will go down to just the utilities' name. (include here if it is available packages on distributions, how to use it etc).

Answer (score 0):

From the complete list I would just add :

- fakeroot (from debian package maintener) : it aims at building package with "friendly" tools. This is not a complete isolation, but it helps building packages with different users and fake devices and other special pseudo-files.
- fakechroot (which uses fakeroot). This program has many bugs. For example,  "/etc/hosts" is hardcoded in glibc : you cannot change it through this tool.
- qemu : you need to compile a linux kernel, but the result is very fast, and this is a "fake" (ie virtual) machine with real root privileges. You can build and mount any boot image.