# Making a process read a different file for the same filename

Tags: files, kernel, system-calls, ld

I have an application that reads a file. Let's call it **processname** and the file *~/.configuration*. When **processname** runs it always reads *~/.configuration* and can't be configured differently. There are also other applications that rely on "~/.configuration", before and after, but not while **processname** is running.

Wrapping **processname** in a script that replaces the contents of *~/.configuration* is an option, but I recently had a power outage (while the contents were swapped out), where I lost the previous contents of said file, so this is not desirable.

Is there a way (perhaps using something distantly related to `LD_DEBUG=files processname`?) for fooling a process into reading different contents when it tries to read a specific file? Searching and replacing the filename in the executable is a bit too invasive, but should work as well.

I know it's possible to write a kernel module that takes over the `open()` call (https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2972958), but is there a simpler or cleaner way?

EDIT: When searching for *~/.configuration* in the **processname** executable I discovered that it tried to read another filename right before reading *~/.configuration*. Problem solved.

Comment: This could be done via `LD_PRELOAD` or FUSE, like with [this somewhat similar problem](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64642/how-to-prevent-a-process-from-writing-files/64745#64745), but I don't know any existing implementation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In recent versions of Linux, you can *unshare* the *mount namespace*. That is, you can start processes that view the virtual file system differently (with file systems mounted differently).

That can also be done with `chroot`, but `unshare` is more adapted to your case.

Like `chroot`, you need superuser priviledged to `unshare` the mount namespace.

So, say you have `~/.configuration` and `~/.configuration-for-that-cmd` files.

You can start a process for which `~/.configuration` is actually a bind-mount of `~/.configuration-for-that-cmd` in there, and execute `that-cmd` in there.

like:

```
sudo unshare -m sh -c "
   mount --bind '$HOME/.configuration-for-that-cmd' \
                '$HOME/.configuration' &&
     exec that-cmd"
```

`that-cmd` and all its descendant processes will see a different `~/.configuration`.

`that-cmd` above will run as `root`, use `sudo -u another-user that-cmd` if it need to run as a *another-user*.

Comment: I think your solution is probably the better of the two given so far (and given what the OP is after, redirecting based on time or the results of a detection process seems iffy to me), but I think they're wanting a single file to show up differently. So they'd probably have to mount it elsewhere and use a symlink, counting on the differing mount points to act as the actual point of redirection.

Comment: @JoelDavis, you can bind-mount any file, not only directory ones.

Comment: TIL. Are there security controls with that, though? I tried it using a subdirectory where I was in (binding from /etc/fstab) and it returned "Not a directory" but I did pretty much the same thing under `/test` and it worked without issue.

Comment: Actually, nm I can see the difference, I did it to a directory first time and a file the next. I was assuming that it would just redirect/modify the VFS as appropriate. Anywho, thanks for the new toy.

Answer (score 3):

Soft links.

Create two config files, and point to one of them with a soft link most of the time, but change the soft link to point to the other one when the special app is running.

(I know this is a horrible hack, but it's slightly more reliable than changing file contents).

Or, manipulate $HOME.

In the script which starts the annoying process, set $HOME to be something under the regular $HOME directory, and your app should then use the config file located there (tested, and works for basic shell commands, ~ expands to $HOME).

Depending on what else the process does, changing $HOME may have unintended consequences (i.e. output files might end up in the wrong place).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using [the LD_PRELOAD trick](https://www.tomaz.me/2014/01/08/detecting-which-process-is-creating-a-file-using-ld-preload-trick.html). Here's an implementation which maps paths beginning with a specific prefix to another location. The code is [also on github](https://github.com/fritzw/ld-preload-open/).

For example, you could fake the existence of a file in `/etc/` without being root. This was necessary for the owncloud client which refuses to work when the file `/etc/ownCloud/sync-exclude.list` does not exist.

It works by overriding the `open()` and `open64()` functions to map one directory to another, for example all `open()` calls to `/etc/ownCloud/...` could be redirected to `/home/user1/.etc/ownCloud/...`.

Just adjust the `path_map`, then compile and run your program with the lib preloaded:

```
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -shared -fPIC path-mapping.c -o path-mapping.so -ldl

LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/my/path-mapping.so someprogram
```

---

Source code of `path-mapping.c`:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <malloc.h>

// List of path pairs. Paths beginning with the first item will be
// translated by replacing the matching part with the second item.
static const char *path_map[][2] = {
    { "/etc/ownCloud/", "/home/user1/.etc/ownCloud/" },
};

__thread char *buffer = NULL;
__thread int buffer_size = -1;

typedef FILE* (*orig_fopen_func_type)(const char *path, const char *mode);
typedef int (*orig_open_func_type)(const char *pathname, int flags, ...);

static int starts_with(const char *str, const char *prefix) {
    return (strncmp(prefix, str, strlen(prefix)) == 0);
}

static char *get_buffer(int min_size) {
    int step = 63;
    if (min_size < 1) {
        min_size = 1;
    }
    if (min_size > buffer_size) {
        if (buffer != NULL) {
            free(buffer);
            buffer = NULL;
            buffer_size = -1;
        }
        buffer = malloc(min_size + step);
        if (buffer != NULL) {
            buffer_size = min_size + step;
        }
    }
    return buffer;
}

static const char *fix_path(const char *path)
{
    int count = (sizeof path_map) / (sizeof *path_map); // Array length
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        const char *prefix = path_map[i][0];
        const char *replace = path_map[i][1];
        if (starts_with(path, prefix)) {
            const char *rest = path + strlen(prefix);
            char *new_path = get_buffer(strlen(path) + strlen(replace) - strlen(prefix));
            strcpy(new_path, replace);
            strcat(new_path, rest);
            printf("Mapped Path: %s  ==>  %s\n", path, new_path);
            return new_path;
        }
    }
    return path;
}


int open(const char *pathname, int flags, ...)
{
    const char *new_path = fix_path(pathname);

    orig_open_func_type orig_func;
    orig_func = (orig_open_func_type)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "open");

    // If O_CREAT is used to create a file, the file access mode must be given.
    if (flags & O_CREAT) {
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, flags);
        int mode = va_arg(args, int);
        va_end(args);
        return orig_func(new_path, flags, mode);
    } else {
        return orig_func(new_path, flags);
    }
}

int open64(const char *pathname, int flags, ...)
{
    const char *new_path = fix_path(pathname);

    orig_open_func_type orig_func;
    orig_func = (orig_open_func_type)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "open64");

    // If O_CREAT is used to create a file, the file access mode must be given.
    if (flags & O_CREAT) {
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, flags);
        int mode = va_arg(args, int);
        va_end(args);
        return orig_func(new_path, flags, mode);
    } else {
        return orig_func(new_path, flags);
    }
}
```