# Use .bashrc be used to modify execution of /usr/bin/env based on PWD

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a `.bashrc` file such that files using the `#!/usr/bin/env` shebang will have their PATH adjusted based on the directory in which they reside.

I've got something towards what I want with the following in my `~/.bashrc`:

```
function env() {
    case $PWD/ in
        /var/www/php73/*)
            PATH=~/bin73;;
        /var/www/php8.1/*)
            PATH=~/bin81;;
    esac
    /usr/bin/env "$@"
}
```

Then if I call `env` from `/var/www/php73` or any subdirectory I get `~/bin73` included in the path as I want.

The problem is that this doesn't work for files which use the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env` as .bashrc is only defining a function for `env`, not the `env` program with its full path.

Is it possible to get `.bashrc` to modify `PATH` when the shebang is used? And if so, how?

Comment: Short of modifying `env` from source code, I really don't think that's possible, `env` is not a trivial shell script and much c processing is involved

Comment: I've got a bit of a rubbish work around, modify `cd`, `pushd` and `popd`, so that `PATH` is updated as necessary based on the current directory. Not elegant, but I think it will do.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you want to achieve. (Maybe run CGI scripts by different PHP versions depending on their location? What web server do you use?) Whose home directory do you expect `~` to represent when your script is called? This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Answer (score 1):

You could write a wrapper for `/usr/bin/env` that does this:

```bash
mv /usr/bin/env /usr/bin/env.bak
cat <<-EOF >/usr/bin/env
    #!/usr/bin/bash
    export PATH="${PWD}:${PATH}"
    /usr/bin/env.bak "$@"
EOF
chmod 755 /usr/bin/env
```

*every* process would use this new `env` though.

If you want just your shell and its children to see this new `env`, this question outlines some solutions: [Making a process read a different file for the same filename](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81003/making-a-process-read-a-different-file-for-the-same-filename)

None of them are perfect though. If you used the accepted solution, a mount namespace, any mounts you made from your shell wouldn't be visible to processes spawned outside your shell.