# Simulate chroot with unshare

Tags: chroot, non-root-user, namespace, unshare

I am trying to write a bootstrapper for a minimal, from-source linux distribution.

I would like to build in a chroot-like environment.  This should simplify packaging. I do not care about security at this point. The bootstrapper should not require any non-standard third-party commands. It would be great if there is no need to be root, either.

This is why fakechroot(1) fakeroot(1) chroot(1) is not exactly what I am looking for.

Is it possible to fake / using unshare(1) and /bin/sh?

Comment: AFAICS, `unshare(1)` is a rather thin wrapper around a collection of root-only system calls, and (at least on Fedora 18) it isn't SUID, so I doubt very much that that will work for non-root users.

Comment: Oh, that's a shame. I was under the impression unshare is setuid. I guess I am fine with being root.

Comment: With the release of the new Linux 3.8 kernel, you can use namespace features as non-root. But this is shiny new stuff: you need a uid namespace first, and unshare does not support that yet. And your actions will still be limited.

Answer (score 8):

Yes. If your [kernel supports user_namespaces (and they are enabled)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/303213/4319), you can first "simulate the root" user, which then gets the right to invoke `chroot` (as a real root user). (Which previously needed to be restricted only to the root user because of [a possibility for privilege escalation by a normal user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/352388/4319) (say, through set-UID-root binaries and custom libraries in the chroot directory).)

You can try this in your shell:

```
unshare --user --map-root-user --mount-proc --pid --fork
/sbin/chroot ......
su - user1
```

Comment: unrecognized option '--map-root-user'

Comment: @Zibri It works for me now, with `unshare` from [util-linux-2.30.2-alt1](https://packages.altlinux.org/en/Sisyphus/srpms/util-linux)

Answer (score 3):

I recently researched how to do this in various Linux distros. The simplest way found was:

`unshare -r chroot <target_folder> <command_w_path>`

For `chroot` to work, the proper libraries and their paths need to be in the target folder. These can be ascertained by using `ldd <command_w_path>` and then copying them with their paths into the target folder. There were minor differences between the distros, for instance Arch Linux needed a symlink from `usr/lib` to `lib` to work.

Answer (score 1):

Just bundle or install fakeroot/fakechroot, since they are already perfectly appropriate for this. Look at cdebootstrap for inspiration.