# Why is chroot(2) unavailable to unprivileged users?

Tags: security, chroot

Why is `chroot(2)` unavailable to unprivileged users?

I don't understand existing answers on the Internet. For example this one https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-security/2003-April/000123.html.

Would `sudo` really work if `/etc/sudoers` and `/etc` were not owned by root? An unprivileged user can't just create root owned setuid binaries inside chroot, can she?

Exactly how can an unprivileged user subvert the chroot environment?

I can only think of something like that

```
ln /mnt/backup/XYZ/etc/sudoers $CHROOT/etc/sudoers
ln /usr/bin/sudo $CHROOT/usr/bin/sudo
```

where `XYZ` denotes some backup instance where admin really screwed up and allowed my user something dangerous. But this is kinda special. Is there any more straightforward way to exploit `chroot(2)` if it was available to unprivileged users?

Answer (score 6):

`chroot(2)` does not change the working directory, so after the call `.` can be outside of the tree rooted at `/`. You can then run any setuid binary from inside the chroot by using a relative path. There are probably many ways to exploit this. For example by modifying `/etc/ld.so.preload` inside your chroot directory you can execute arbitrary code with root privileges. You can have a look at an [example](https://github.com/aykit/chroot-privilege-escalation).

Answer (score 4):

An ordinary user can't create a setuid binary, but there's nothing preventing him from creating a hard link to an existing setuid binary. So if he has write permission to a directory on the same filesystem as `/usr/bin`, he can put the jail in this directory, create a hard link to `su` or `sudo` in it, and put a custom `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/sudoers` in the jail.

Maybe that won't work for `sudo`, as it might check that `/etc/sudoers` is owned by root. But I'll bet `su` doesn't check the ownership of `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: This in no longer an issue in Linux 3.6 and later, where the creation of hardlinks requires the user to own the existing file or have read/write access to it. See https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/patch/315952/.

Answer (score 4):

According to Brad Spengler on https://forums.grsecurity.net/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=2522, there is a trivial way to escalate to uid 0 using `CAP_SYS_CHROOT` (the capability to use `chroot(2)`:

> CAP_SYS_CHROOT: generic: From Julien Tinnes/Chris Evans: if you have write access to the same filesystem as a suid root binary, set up a chroot environment with a backdoored libc and then execute a hardlinked suid root binary within your chroot and gain full root privileges through your backdoor

Comment: This in no longer an issue in Linux 3.6 and later, where the creation of hardlinks requires the user to own the existing file or have read/write access to it. See https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/patch/315952/.