# How to achieve the effect of chroot in userspace in Linux (without being root)?

Tags: non-root-user, virtualization, chroot, jails

The goal is to install and run programs in a displaced (relocated) distro (whose / must not coincide with the global /) inside a host Linux system. The programs are not adapted for using a different / .

fakechroot is not a complete solution because it employs library-substitution instead of acting on the level of system calls (so not good for statically linked binaries).

Comment: Cf. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66084/simulate-chroot-with-unshare

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution must probably be based either on ptrace or [namespaces (unshare)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66084/simulate-chroot-with-unshare).

ptrace-based solutions are probably less efficient then namespaces/unshare-based (but the latter technology is cutting-edge and is not well explored path, probably).

### ptrace-based

#### UMView

As for ptrced-based solutions, thanks to the comments at https://stackoverflow.com/a/1019720/94687, I've discovered UMView:

- http://wiki.virtualsquare.org/wiki/index.php/ViewFS
- http://wiki.virtualsquare.org/wiki/index.php/Virtual_installation_of_software

The linked docs describe how to have a "copy-on-write view" of the host fs -- that's not exactly like performing a chroot. Exact intructions on how to achieve /-substitution in umview would be nice to have in an answer to my question (please write one if you figure out how to do this!).

umview must be open-source, because it is included in Ubuntu and Debian -- http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/umview.

#### "Confining programs"

Another implementation is described in http://www.cs.vu.nl/~rutger/publications/jailer.pdf, http://www.cs.vu.nl/~guido/mansion/publications/ps/secrypt07.pdf.

They have a change-root-ing policy rule, CHRDIR, whose effect is similar to chroot. (Section "The jailing policy")

However, they might have not published their source code (partially based on a modified strace http://www.liacs.nl/~wichert/strace/ -- Section "Implementation")...

#### geordi

Geordi (http://www.eelis.net/geordi/, https://github.com/Eelis/geordi) could probably be modified to make the wanted rewriting of file arguments to system calls in the jailed programs.

#### proot

[PRoot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44284/4319) is a ready to use ptrace-based tool for this. http://proot.me/:

> chroot equivalent
>
> To execute a command inside a given Linux distribution, just give
>   proot the path to the guest rootfs followed by the desired command.
>   The example below executes the program cat to print the content of a
>   file:
>
> ```
> proot -r /mnt/slackware-8.0/ cat /etc/motd
>
> Welcome to Slackware Linux 8.0
> ```
>
> The default command is /bin/sh when none is specified. Thus the
>   shortest way to confine an interactive shell and all its sub-programs
>   is:
>
> ```
> proot -r /mnt/slackware-8.0/
>
> $ cat /etc/motd
> Welcome to Slackware Linux 8.0
> ```

### unshare-based

[user_namespaces support in the Linux kernel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/303213/4319) has got more mature since when the question was asked. Now you can play with performing a `chroot` as a normal with the help of `unshare` like in [Simulate chroot with unshare](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/303660/4319):

```
unshare --user --map-root-user --mount-proc --pid --fork
chroot ......
su - user1
```

Comment: You ask and answer simultaneosly?

Comment: @HaukeLaging It's [encouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking) if you think the info will be useful for others

Comment: @HaukeLaging As I posed this question to myself (and started writing the question down), I started searching for the solutions, so very soon I got already an understanding of the possible solutions, and wrote that down as an answer. A bit later I discoveren one more tool to do this (proot), perhaps the most convenient, and added it to the answer.

Comment: bubblewrap is a really nice unshare-based chroot/mount --bind replacement: https://github.com/projectatomic/bubblewrap

Answer (score 1):

You could try [User-Mode Linux](http://user-mode-linux.sourceforge.net/). The code for building such a kernel is now present in the mainstream sources, and you can find (outdated) precompiled builds on the page I linked.